# Get thread information in Xamarin PCL

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, portable-class-library

I start some parallel tasks from a PCL with

`Parallel.Invoke(() => ExecuteTaskAAsync(), () => ExecuteTaskBAsync());`

Now I want to know on which thread these tasks are running.

`Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId` seems to be only available in the iOS 
and Droid project but not in the PCL or UWP project. What are my possibilities? If I would use `DependencyService` I also won't know on which thread TaskA is running, because there is not relationship between the started task and `DependencyService`.

How can I get thread information (id, name, ...) in a PCL?

When you set a breakpoint you can get into the [Tasks Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd998369.aspx) and get some more information. Also you have a drop down on the top to select a process, choose between different threads and get some info about the stack frame. So one should be able to also get this information in code?

**Edit:**

Seems that the informations in the Tasks Window is only available when running on UWP.

Comment: Is the explicit thread ID really a requirement? If not you can check for 'SynchronizationContext.Current' and check if they are equal to some stored reference.

Comment: No it's not. I want to include some thread information in the log file to see what came from which thread. With your comparing approach I can only see if it's a non UI thread? In my sample app `SynchronizationContext` was `null`.

Comment: You can set TracePoints in Visual Studio, where you can output the Thread ID to the debug window.

Comment: Now I tried to set a breakpoint with action `context = {context}`, whereas `SynchronizationContext context = SynchronizationContext.Current;`. The result was `context = (null)`. Then I tried it with `thread = $TID` and the result was `thread = 0x6`. Did you mean that? How can I access something like that in code?

Comment: I meant the $TID. You really shouldn't need to use the threadId in code. But as ThreadId seems not to be available in a PCL, your only option is to create an interface and dependency inject a platform specific implementation...

Comment: On the other Hand: MSDN states, that the ManagedThreadId property is available on UWP and i just tried it and it worked for me. Are you using the right PCL-Profile?

Comment: The `DependencyService` from [Xamarin](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/) imho instantiates a new object if I would try to natively access the thread id. How should the `DependencyService` know on which thread a task runs? There is no relationship in my eyes. In the *.csproj* the following PCL-Profile is used `<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile111</TargetFrameworkProfile>`. I tried to access `ManagedThreadId` in *App.xaml.cs* if thats makes a difference. Which code did you use?

Comment: Ah sorry, i accidently created a 8.1 universal app... Looks like all APIs regarding Threads have been removed in win10. (Also the doc says something different.)

Comment: Just found this: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2576 So it looks like the answer to your question is, that it's currently not possible. You might try if `TaskSchedule.Current` helps you out.

Comment: You could post your comment as an answer. `TaskScheduler.Current` is available. Which information I can get out of it? As I have seen I get the id of the task scheduler. Are there any more information available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The concept of threads is completely absent in Windows Universal Apps and the use of tasks is recommended instead of threads.

I haven't found official documentation on the reasons behind it, but there's an ongoing discussion [at the CoreFX's github repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2576).

So it looks like what you are looking for isn't currently possible if you want to support UWP projects.

You mal alternatively look for the `TaskScheduler` that manages the currently running task:

```
var poolId = TaskScheduler.Current.Id;
```

This way you can at least find out, if your method is running on the same *ThreadPool* (eg: They are executed on any background threads, or the UI thread).

As far as I know, to find the TaskScheduler for the UI, you have to call `TaskScheduler.Current.Id` while you are on the UI Thread and just store it in a variable.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

`Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId`